# In Trello, how to get the sender mail in "email to board" functionality?

Tags: trello

In Trello, Am using email to board functionality for creating tickets for my team. So i would like to know who send the email in the board ticket. 
Ticket is getting raised with the email to board functionality but am not able to get the sender email id so that i can keep track of that.
Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a related question that I asked on the Attlassian community.

I was forwarding automatically to the board rather than emailing directly so the answer maybe will not help you situation.

They suggested using Zapier to connect Gmail to Trello.

The answer on the Attlassian community is  [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Trello-questions/Email-to-Board-Get-originating-email-address/qaq-p/715920?utm_source=atlcomm&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=solution_to_question&utm_content=topic)